# Logical Search Field Database Select issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, node.js, search

This is a somewhat complex but simple issue.  I am creating a small application that allows the storing on an object, that object has a title, description, tags, and sub-objects.  the subjects contain comments.  What would be an ideal way to use a search field to find any matches in these objects.

e.g.
object 1 {id:1, title:test, description:fun, tags:[{games, toys}]}
subobject 1 {lid:1, comment:'this is fun and fast'}

say i search: fun fast.
or i search: test

i would like any of those to return the same object.

I understand i will have to explode the variable by space or comma and create an array, but how exactly should i construct the sql.

I am not trying to create a sophisticated page rank algrothim, if i have to restrict to search by title or tag or description i will do so.

note: this is a simple app, im just looking for options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to combine your fields into a JSON object, and place that in MongoDB or another JSON db

Comment: Brilliant! its too late to use mongo, but when i get the object in the first place it is one big json including the sub object, i will just stick that in a file on the server, if there is a match in the object, i will grab the list id and select that from the database!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know is to use the PostgreSQL trigram searches.  Assuming you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, '{id:1, title:test, description:fun, tags:[{games, toys}]} subobject 1 {lid:1, comment:''this is fun and fast''}');
```

You could prepare for searches with this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX t_trgm ON t USING gin (value gin_trgm_ops);
SELECT set_limit(0.05);
```

You only need to install the extension once per database.  You can use GiST or GIN indexing; just use the corresponding operations set.  GiST is generally faster to update; GIN is generally faster to search -- so the best choice depends on the workload.  I set the similarity limit on the connection to 5% because you seem to be happy with matches on small portions of the string.  Adjust as necessary.  Remember this limit is session-based, so you need to set it up on the connection before you use the % operator.

Having done that setup, here are the searches:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE value % 'test';
SELECT * FROM t WHERE value % 'fun fast';
```

It doesn't get too much simpler than that.

While it probably won't even *use* the index when you only have one row in the table, we have found in our production databases with millions of rows to search, a similarity search will generally run in a few tens of milliseconds.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html